# Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli) - MAC OS X

Tags: java, macos, maven

**This is my java version:** java -version

> java version "1.8.0_20" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.8.0_20-b26) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)

**And my bash_profile:**

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home
M2_HOME=/Users/michaelkees/apache-maven-3.3.9
M2=/Users/michaelkees/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin
PATH=/Users/michaelkees/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:/Users/michaelkees/Documents/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/sbin
```

- Maven 3.3.9 is installed

When I try to use the command : **'mvn -v'**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

Comment: what does `mvn -c` do?  Also, what does `java -version` show you from the command prompt?

Comment: **mvn -c** gives me the Exception major.minor version 51.0
and **java - version** java version "1.8.0_20" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)

Comment: what does mvn -c do?: FROM THE SITE OF MAVEN: "Add the bin directory of the created directory apache-maven-3.3.9 to the PATH environment variable

Confirm with mvn -v in a new shell. The result should look similar to". Its -v , but It gives the same error

Comment: I just never knew about -c.  According to doc I read -c/-C is:
'The following command line options affect the way that Maven will interact with remote repositories and how it verifies downloaded artifacts:

-C, --strict-checksums
Fail the build if checksums don’t match
-c, --lax-checksums
Warn if checksums don’t match
-U, --update-snapshots
Forces a check for updated releases and snapshots on remote repositories'

Comment: even when i use the command : **mvn** without an option it gives me the exception major.minor version 51

Comment: It's got to be that mvn is not using the 1.8 JVM you think it is.  Most probably it is running with a 1.6 JVM as class format version 51.0 corresponds to 1.7 JVM (which 1.6 JVM knows nothing about).  You could go into the mvn bash shell script and add a line to echo out $JAVACMD and see where it points to.

Comment: From the top of my head, I'd say try to see if `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version` actually works. Like previous posts before this, I agree with the notion that `mvn` is picking up the wrong version of Java.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Run configuration and choose Java 7 or Java 8 for maven version above then 3.2.X
Maven 3.3 required higher Java version.

Answer (score 0):

Is you output of your `.bash_profile` what you have posted? If so than you need to change it cause the environment variables will not made available to sub processes. You need to use the following in your `.bash_profile`:

```sh
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=/Users/michaelkees/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:$PATH
```

After you have changed it you need to make a new login.

An other approach is to define `JAVA_HOME´ via`.mavenrc` file which might be a little bit more flexible.

You need to create a file `.mavenrc`  in your home directory `$HOME/.mavenrc` which contains a line like this:

```sh
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Than you don't need to define `JAVA_HOME` in your `.bash_profile`.